# How to test an API endpoint that has a function inside which is itself tested?

Tags: python, api, mocking, pytest, fastapi

I'm developing a web app in FastAPI and now I'm trying to develop some unit test.

I'm working on this endpoint, *route_baseline.py*:

```
@router.post("/search")
def search(lat: float, lon: float, request: Request):
    try:
        climate_zone, egrid_zone, state = get_region_info(lat, lon)
    except (IndexError, Exception):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Selected coordinates not within US boundaries.",
        )
    return state
```

This same endpoint calls a function, *location_service.py*:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import geometry as g

data_path = dirname(__file__) + "/../../../database/data"

def geopandas_read_file(filename):
    return gpd.read_file(join(data_path, filename))

def get_region_info(lat, lon):
    # Create geometry object with (lat, lon) point
    point = g.Point(lat, lon)
    # Read U.S. States Shapefiles
    gdf_states = geopandas_read_file("USA_States_(Generalized).zip")
    # Query State
    states_query = gdf_states[gdf_states.geometry.intersects(point)]
    state = states_query.STATE_ABBR.values[0]
    return state
```

And for it I have developed two unit tests, *test_location_service.py*:

```
import core.location_service as ls
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import geopandas as gpd
class TestCoreLocationService(TestCase):
    f1 = gpd.read_file("tests/test_core/data/USA_States_(Generalized).zip")

    def test_coords_valid(self):
        with patch("core.location_service.geopandas_read_file", side_effect=[self.f1, self.f2, self.f3]) as geopandas_read_file_patched:
            assert ls.get_region_info(-74.50, 40.34) == ("4A", "RFCE", "NJ")

    def test_coords_invalid(self):
        with patch("core.location_service.geopandas_read_file", side_effect=[self.f1, self.f2, self.f3]) as geopandas_read_file_patched:
            self.assertRaises(IndexError, ls.get_region_info, 0, 0)
```

Tests for search endpoint, *test_baseline.py*:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
@patch('core.location_service.get_region_info')
def test_search_valid(client, mock_requests):
    mock_requests.return_value = "NJ"
    response = client.post("/baseline/search?lat=-74.59&lon=40.34")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response.json()[0] == "NJ"

def test_search_invalid(client):
    response = client.post("/baseline/search?lat=0&lon=0")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    assert response.json() == {"detail": "Selected coordinates not within US boundaries."}
```

The problem is that when the tests run in the CI/CD pipeline the first test_search_valid fails because geopandas cannot find the .zip file because of the variable data_path. So to do test_coords_valid and test_coords_invalid I had to import the .zip file into the repository for the location_service tests to pass, and now my idea was somehow when I ran the search tests that it would call the location_service tests... Does that make sense?

Are these not integration tests?

Can I create a test for the search endpoint that calls the tests for get_region_info? I tried with side_effect but I was not able to put it working.

Comment: I need some further info to try to help you. What is it the `ls` object in the test code? Can you edit your question and add other parts of the test code file. For example add the import that file please.

Comment: @frankfalse thank you for your willingness to help, let me know if it's better.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to help you.. At least not at this moment

Comment: Does it make sense what I said? By what I can search a solution for this?

Comment: Try to patch() the function `get_region_info()` in `test_search_valid()` and `test_search_invalid()`. You can use @patch('test_core.test_location_service.get_region_info'), so `test_search_valid()` has the argument `mock_get_region`. Inside `test_search_valid()` set 'mock_get_region.return_value=('NJ')'. For `test_search_invalid()` you need to raise an `HTTPException`.  This is only a hint, I don't know if it is useful for you

Comment: I correct the previous comment: not `@patch('test_core.test_location_service.get_region_info')` but `@patch('core.location_service.get_region_info')`. You have to patch() the real function `get_region()`

Comment: Thank you @frankfalse for your help! I had already arrived at that solution but it raises a conceptual doubt... Since the endpoint is to call the function get_region_info, what is the use of this? Basically it's assigning the value to the mock and reading from it :)

Comment: The test `test_coords_valid()` guarantees that `get_region_info()` works well. With `test_search_valid()` and  `test_search_invalid()`, you are testing `search()` and this is possible by the retun_value set for `get_region_info()`.

Comment: If you want write your own answer, with all your code, so we can discuss about it more easily.

Comment: I tried to patch the real function by calling the endpoint with `response = client.post("/baseline/search?lat=-74.59&lon=40.34")` and it returns that it does not find the mock function (I updated the question).

Comment: Sorry, I think that the correct patch for `test_search_valid()` is: `@patch('core.route_baseline.get_region_info')` where I suppose that the file `route_baseline.py` is in the package `core` where there is also `location_service.py`. I hope that with this patch `mock_requests` is accessible! Sorry for the hits not precise but I didn't execute your code till now.

Comment: No problem, thank you for all your tips! Have a good one